# How to create an animation similar to Github's file manager one?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to add to a page the same animation present in Github's file manager, that appears when you navigate the tree: the box slides laterally, making space for another one.

Current structure is (simplified):

```
<div class="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#foo" class="selected">Foo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#etc">Etc 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#bla">Bla bla</a></li>
    <li><a href="#fourth">Fourth tab</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- Tabs content -->
<div class="content">
  <div id="#foo"></div>
  <div id="#etc"></div>
  <div id="#bla"></div>
  <div id="#fourth"></div>
</div>
```

So, when a tab becomes `selected`, the previous tab content should slide laterally like Github's filemanager, and make space for the current content. I havan't been able to discover it from Github's code, so I ask here. If possible, this should require only CSS, but a Javascript solution is well accepted (only if does not require animation libraries).

I thought I could use the CSS pseudo-selector `:target` to make this work, but I haven't figured out the animation part yet.

Comment: How about using javascript slider plugin?

Comment: @hrr: Didn't know about that! Is it JQuery? Then it's ok. I'm checking it out.

Comment: @hrr: That is almost great. However, in the docs it says I can't use my own pagination, and that's what is needed for the 4 tabs above. It would be great if there were some functions like `go_to_slide(number)`. That really would be perfect.

Comment: Ah nice, I found this: http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/?rdfrom=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jquery.com%2Fmw%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DUI%2FEffects%2FSlide%26redirect%3Dno. It's even part of JQuery, so I just need to understand how to adapt it to my case.

Comment: Correction: it's not part of JQuery but of JQuery UI.

Comment: Notice also that Github changes the URL along with the file. You'll have to use the HTML 5 history API if you want to achieve that.

Comment: @WaleedKhan: Ah thanks! Didn't know about HTML5 history eh :) I'll rember this for another task. Do you know about the other problem? (See my own answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
There was no need to use timeouts, I discovered that JQuery effects supports callbacks. So, after replacing `toggle` with the more apt `show` and `hide`, it works beautifully:

```
var tabs = $('.tabs ul li a')
tabs.click(function () {
    var previous = tabs.filter('.selected');
    // Prevent the event to happen if the user clicks the currently
    // selected tab
    if (previous.attr('href') === $(this).attr('href')) {
        return;
    }
    var direction = tabs.index($(this)) - tabs.index(previous);
    var options = direction > 0 ? [{direction: 'left'}, {direction: 'right'}] :
                                  [{direction: 'right'}, {direction: 'left'}]
    previous.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    var previous_content = $(previous.attr('href'));
    var this_content = $($(this).attr('href'));
    previous_content.hide('slide', options[0], 300, function () {
        this_content.show('slide', options[1], 300);
    });
});
```

I even added this to handle keypresses (left and right arrow keys):

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    var direction;
    switch (e.which) {
        case 37:
            direction = -1;
            break;
        case 39:
            direction = 1;
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
    var next = tabs.index(tabs.filter('.selected')) + direction;
    if (next < 0 || next >= tabs.length) return;
    tabs.eq(next).trigger('click');
    return false;
});
```